# How to build a protection for your head, neck and back for practicing new flips!

Tags: safety

I recently stumbled upon a YouTuber called "pigmie" who didn't get over the fear of doing a double backflip as he could land on his head and get a serious injury. So he build his own protection (the "moonsuit"):

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jnfqBUw6gg   <--- minute 1:00

This moonsuit is build out of many pieces of a (rather thin) gymnast-mattress. And he got over the fear!

But this suit is not really secure ... I mean, it's hard to get a serious head-neck-back injury with it, but its still not as convenient as I wish my protection to be!

This is how he build it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkmngpiISf0&t=627s

But there must be an easier protection... maybe a neck-protection with a motocross-helmed or a ruff? I don't know if thats a good idea...?

What's important is that I should still be able to do front and backflips and that my back is safe from overbending too!

Comment: Don't really want to comment on the lifehackiness or anything. But welcome to Lifehacks.SE and thanks for sharing this! Got a good laugh out of me.

Comment: @Alex thanks!
To the "put on hold"-voter: I think it's on topic! It's not one of those "how to..."-questions mentioned in the advice for which questions are on-topic. It may need out of the box thinking (you don't know which answers are possible until someone writes them (with outside the box thinking)). And it's not a "mind hack"-question, I don't need to hack anything. I don't want to trick my mind to think that nothing can happen by doing a double backflip - I really want that nothing can happen.